# Replace several characters in a text file using specific row and column values of a csv

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a `.txt` file with different entries such as `region1a`, `region1b`, `region2a`, region2b etc.

I have an excel file with different column and row values. I want to use a particular row and column value with to replace say `region1` in the text file, and a different column and row value to replace `region2`, ... like that.

I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks for your assistance.

- The sample excel files looks like this:

  [image: The sample excel files looks like this:]
- The text file looks like below

  ```
  p1 (region1a    region1b -0.1);
  p2 (region1a    region1b 5);

  p1 (region2a    region2b -0.1);
  p2 (region2a    region2b 5);
  ```
- Expected output

  ```
  p1 (-0.01703    0.08515 -0.1);
  p2 (-0.01703    0.08515 5);

  p1 (0.02297 0.08515  -0.1);
  p2 (0.02297 0.08515  5);
  ```

[image: This is a sample of the excel file]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample CSV and text file input and corresponding output.

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of details. I have attached a sample text and csv file. thanks

Comment: You say that you want to replace (for example) region 1, but with what? Can you also provide the desired result for your example?

Comment: The expected output looks like this. The excel data is used to replace the text entries. since there are lots of entries, I want a particular cell value to replace a name inside the text file

p1 (-0.01703 0.08515 -0.1);
p2 (-0.01703 0.08515 5);

p1 (0.02297 0.08515  -0.1);
p2 (0.02297 0.08515  5);

Comment: How is `region2a` and `region1b5` in one file determined to be the same as `regiona` and `regionb` in the other?  Also, at the start of the question you mention `region1`, `region2` etc.  These do not seem to be anywhere.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have modified the files to provide more clarity. Thanks

Comment: You could use a combination of `awk` and `sed`. `awk` converts the CSV file into `sed` substitution expressions of the type `s/region1a/-0.01703/g`, which it writes to a file. Then, use `sed` to perform those substitutions on the text file.

Comment: @berndbausch could you please provide a sample code to help my case?. also instead of explicitly writing -0.01703, is there a way to access the column and row value which in this case is C2(using excel column row naming style ) for -0.01703?

Comment: No, this task looks too complex to do it for free. I did not mean to write explicitly -0.01703, but to get the number from the content of the CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from this csv (`input.csv`)

```
no,a,b
region1,-0.01703,0.08515
region2,0.02297,0.08515
```

you can convert it to this TSV (`out.tsv`)

```
region1a    -0.01703
region1b    0.08515
region2a    0.02297
region2b    0.08515
```

using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```bsh
mlr --c2t reshape -i a,b -o item,value then put '$field=$no.$item' then cut -o -f field,value ./input.csv | tail -n +2 >./out.tsv
```

The second file you have is this (`input.txt`)

```
p1 (region1a    region1b -0.1);
p2 (region1a    region1b 5);

p1 (region2a    region2b -0.1);
p2 (region2a    region2b 5);
```

Then you could run simply a for loop in a bash script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -x

cp ./input.txt ./output.txt
while IFS=$'\t' read -r region value; do
    sed -i -r 's/'"$region"'/'"$value"'/g' ./output.txt
done <./out.tsv
```

The `output.txt` will be

```
p1 (-0.01703    0.08515 -0.1);
p2 (-0.01703    0.08515 5);

p1 (0.02297    0.08515 -0.1);
p2 (0.02297    0.08515 5);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this wonderful solution @aborruso

Comment: You are welcome @DelaQuarme

Comment: @DelaQuarme What was the problem you had? How did you solve it?
You told me it didn't work for you before

Comment: Yes, I didn't indent the bash code well so it was not creating the right text to replace the other text file. But after correcting the indenting, everything worked excellently. Thanks again @aborruso